# How to input a UTF-8 text file in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents

I want to use PHP to read a plain text file containing mixed ASCII and Japanese characters encoded in UTF-8. I've tried:

```
$input = file_get_contents('filename');
```

However, this converts all Japanese characters to "?", when I print them on a page with this header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I've tried creating the file with and without a UTF-8 signature, but that made no difference. I'm using PHP 5.5.1 on Windows 7 with IIS.

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the files themselves are saved as UTF-8 and not ANSI. You may have to experiment with using "with or without BOM". Try and provide full code and the file/characters used.

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not convert anything to anything, it gives you the raw bytes in the file. You'll have to produce a more complete test case/demonstration of the problem.